# i received BTC on testnet and the sender said that it is de-activated..it will be activated after I pay a certain fee?

Tags: testnet

a trader sent me  2 bitcoins on testnet to show that i will receive more after they activate it...I have to pay a certain fee before they activate it

Answer (score 2):

> **a trader sent me 2 bitcoins on testnet**

testnet Bitcoins are worth nothing.

> **I have to pay a certain fee before they activate it**

You are communicating with a criminal confidence trickster who is only pretending to be a trader.

Answer (score 1):

Testnet is a completely separate network, there is no way to ‘activate’ or otherwise move coins between the bitcoin testnet and bitcoin network. Testnet coins are worthless by definition, that is why they are useful to developers who want to test their code without risking funds.

As @redgrittybrick mentioned, you are dealing with a scammer. Do not send them money.